# Kafka streams: Read from ALL partitions in every instance of an application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partitioning, apache-kafka-streams

When using KTable, Kafka streams doesn't allow instances to read from multiple partitions of a particular topic when the number of instances / consumers is equal to number of partitions. I tried achieving this using GlobalKTable, the problem with this is that data will be overwritten, also aggregation cannot be applied on it.

Let's suppose I have a topic named "data_in" with 3 partitions (P1, P2, P3). When I run 3 instances (I1, I2, I3) of a Kafka streaming application, I want each instance to read data from all partitions of "data_in". I mean that I1 can read from P1, P2 and P3, I2 can read from P1, P2 and P3, I2 and on and on.

**EDIT: Keep in mind, that the producer can publish two similar IDs into two different partitions in "data_in". So when running two different instances, GlobalKtable will be overwritten.**

Please, how to achieve this? This a portion of my code

```
private KTable<String, theDataList> globalStream() {

    // KStream of records from data-in topic using String and theDataSerde deserializers
    KStream<String, Data> trashStream = getBuilder().stream("data_in",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerDes.theDataSerde));

    // Apply an aggregation operation on the original KStream records using an intermediate representation of a KStream (KGroupedStream)
    KGroupedStream<String, Data> KGS = trashStream.groupByKey();

    Materialized<String, theDataList, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized = Materialized.as("agg-stream-store");
    materialized = materialized.withValueSerde(SerDes.theDataDataListSerde);

    // Return a KTable
    return KGS.aggregate(() -> new theDataList(), (key, value, aggregate) -> {
        if (!value.getValideData())
            aggregate.getList().removeIf((t) -> t.getTimestamp() <= value.getTimestamp());
        else
            aggregate.getList().add(value);
        return aggregate;
    }, materialized);
}
```

Comment: each instance of your app has to be in different consumer group.

Comment: We tried this. In every instance we created two builders (B1, B2). B1 reads data from all partitions, so every instance has a unique ID. B2 reads data from one partition of another topic (not data_in). Later, when we do join, we get this error `Invalid topology: StateStore agg-stream-store is not added yet` cuz B1 and B2 have difeffrent APP_ID

Comment: We want to do a join of all the data in **data_in** (read from all partitions) with just one partition of another topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the number of partitions of your input topic "data_in" to 1 partition or use a `GlobalKtable` to get data from all partitions in the topic and then you can join your stream with it. With that, your apps instances no longer have to be in different consumer group.

The code will look like this :

```
private GlobalKTable<String, theDataList> globalStream() {

   // KStream of records from data-in topic using String and theDataSerde deserializers
  KStream<String, Data> trashStream = getBuilder().stream("data_in", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerDes.theDataSerde));

  thrashStream.to("new_data_in"); // by sending to an other topic you're forcing a repartition on that topic

  KStream<String, Data> newTrashStream = getBuilder().stream("new_data_in", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerDes.theDataSerde));

  // Apply an aggregation operation on the original KStream records using an intermediate representation of a KStream (KGroupedStream)
  KGroupedStream<String, Data> KGS = newTrashStream.groupByKey();

  Materialized<String, theDataList, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized = Materialized.as("agg-stream-store");
  materialized = materialized.withValueSerde(SerDes.theDataDataListSerde);

// Return a KTable
  KGS.aggregate(() -> new theDataList(), (key, value, aggregate) -> {
      if (!value.getValideData())
          aggregate.getList().removeIf((t) -> t.getTimestamp() <= value.getTimestamp());
      else
        aggregate.getList().add(value);
      return aggregate;
  }, materialized)
  .to("agg_data_in");

  return getBuilder().globalTable("agg_data_in");
}
```

EDIT : I edited the code above to force a repartition on a topic called "new_data_in".

Comment: Are you sure that data won't be overwritten using GlobalKTable?

Comment: Am afraid that as data coming in, the old data in the GlobalKTable will be overwritten when there is same IDs

Comment: I mean, each instance would just be overwriting the other instances' aggregations on each update to the global table.

Comment: Normally when data keep coming in the topic "data_in" it will compute the aggregate method that you create and write the result into the new topic "agg_data_in".
After that you will have to do a join between a stream from the other topic that you mentioned and the globalktable from "agg_data_in".

Comment: Thanks! Am asking about updates into the GlobalKTable from agg_data_in? According to my knowledge updates to GlobalKTable are overwritten (if a new data comes, and found its key there, it will overwrite the old data / value).

Comment: Yes, normally you're right, but in the code that I change above, we write into a new topic (from this topic we create a `GlobalKtable` after in the code ) after doing an aggregation on the data, so the data key that's coming into the new topic are already unique ! 
An example : `(1, ['for'])` is coming and then many time later `(1,['ward'])` coming, it will compute the aggregation method and add the value to the list, so the resulting result into the topic (and then on associated `GlobalKtable`) will be : `(1, ['for','ward'])`.

Comment: However be careful, using `GlobalKtable` mean that all (all your partitions) your data from the underlying topic will be loaded into the store. Verify that all your data fits into your store.

Comment: Now I feel like I have 4 eyes, thanks a lot @Saïd! Okay, I will test this. And if it works I will come back and accept your answer as a solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: actually your solution should solve the problem, the only issue that prevents that (from our side) is that the producer can publish two similar IDs in two different partitions in "data_in". So when running two different instances, GlobalKtable will be overwritten.

Comment: Okay now I understand, either you have a typical business but normally it's consider a bad practice to send data with same keys on different partitions unless you know exactly what you're doing. The solution to your problem will be to force a repartition before the aggregate method by sending data to an other topic and then doing an aggregate on thoses records coming from it.

Comment: You're right! It's better to be autonomous, so solving the problem in our side (problematically) is far better than trying to find a way to publish the data as per our need, especially when the number of data sources increase. **Please, how might this (force a re-partition before the aggregate) be accomplished? At least share some starting points (ideas, steps, tutorial, code snipets, ...) **

Comment: I just edited my answer above, tell me if it's works !

Comment: Sure, I will be back soon!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185152/discussion-between-ahmed-djebali-and-said-bouras).

Comment: By the way now, if you send immediately data to an intermediate topic for re partitioning, you can use Ktable instead of GlobalKtable, the data will be correctly partitioned and the operations (aggregate, joins etc..) will be computed per partitions normally. Unless you have a particulary need to have all your data into all instances of your app, in this case keep the GlobalKtable.